# Apache server not working locally in ubuntu showing an error " Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server." on terminal

Tags: laravel, apache, ubuntu, lamp

> ```
> user@user-desktop:~$ sudo service apache2 restart
> Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
> See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
> user@user-desktop:~$ systemctl status apache2.service
> ● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
>    Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
>   Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
>            └─apache2-systemd.conf
>    Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2018-09-18 16:45:15 IST; 7s ago
>   Process: 12099 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
>
> Sep 18 16:45:14 user-desktop systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
> Sep 18 16:45:14 user-desktop apachectl[12099]: apache2: Syntax error on line 225 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line
> ```
>
> 14 of /etc
>       Sep 18 16:45:15 user-desktop apachectl[12099]: Action 'start' failed.
>       Sep 18 16:45:15 user-desktop apachectl[12099]: The Apache error log may have more information.
>       Sep 18 16:45:15 user-desktop systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
>       Sep 18 16:45:15 user-desktop systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
>       Sep 18 16:45:15 user-desktop systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.

Comment: As the error log says: `Syntax error on line 225 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:`. Check what's wrong with that line of the config file.

Comment: @ImeshaSudasingha Syntax error on line 225 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 14 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/laravel.conf: </VirtualHost>^O> directive missing closing '>' Action 'configtest' failed. The Apache error log may have more information.

 how to change the conf file from laravael.conf to default.conf ??

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED

Changed the conf file from laravel.conf to default conf file ie 000-default.conf

Comment: Downvoted because it is faster to read logs than post here.